# FTPClient: Not getting timed Out exception

Tags: java, ftp-client

I am using following code for uploading file. it works fine but the problem is that in uploading process arbitrary on a file it got hanged (No idea what is the reason).

-May be file is too long.

-May be Connection is not working fine.

but it remains hanged and finally i have to terminate it manually. so if there is any thing wrong then how can i get recognize time out doesn't matter whatever the reason just skip that file with some error.

```
FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
FileInputStream fis = null;


try {
    client.connect("32.178.10.121");
    client.login("XXX", "XXX");

    //
    // Create an InputStream of the file to be uploaded
    //

    File f = new File("D:\\FileFolder");
    if (f.isDirectory())
    {
        File[] listFiles = f.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < listFiles.length; i++)
        {
            String filename = listFiles[i].getName();
            fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            client.storeFile(filename, fis);

        }
    }

    //
    // Store file to server
    //
    client.logout();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        if (fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        client.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is you can do your file upload in a thread. And you can timeout this thread if it is taking long time.

You can use **ExecutorService** service for this purpose.

Check this link for how to implement ExecutorService:
[How to timeout a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread)

Are you using apache commons FtpClient? 
if so you can try using **getStatus()** to to continuously poll the status and close in case of some error. 
Or you can set timeout using **setDataTimeout(int timeout)** method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JDK 1.7 I would recommend trying to downgrade to 1.6. It seems FTP is buggy in java 7, especially if you are using JDK's libraries. I was doing a program and it just froze my computer completely and would upload on and on but downgrading worked for me. If it's a larger application make another project with JDK 1.6 set and try just the FTP part.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(300);`

See (possible duplicate): [Commons FTPClient hangs after uploading large a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530240/commons-ftpclient-hangs-after-uploading-large-a-file)